# Rblpapi - Error

Tags: r, finance, bloomberg, rblpapi

I use Rblpapi package on a PC at work. I've tried to install it on my Mac at home, however, I get the below error. I'm not sure what the problem is... all other packages work. Any suggestions?

> library(Rblpapi)
>   Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/Users/wg/Library/R/3.3/library/Rblpapi/libs/Rblpapi.so':
>     dlopen(/Users/wg/Library/R/3.3/library/Rblpapi/libs/Rblpapi.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libblpapi3_64.so
>     Referenced from: /Users/wg/Library/R/3.3/library/Rblpapi/libs/Rblpapi.so
>     Reason: image not found
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rblpapi’

Comment: See the System Requirements on the [Rblpapi CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rblpapi/index.html). Do you have a valid Bloomberg installation on your Mac?

Comment: Yes, I have a valid instance of Bloomberg on my Mac. The library is installed, the namespace fails to load.

Comment: You installed it with `install.packages()`? I'm very surprised that it can't find a shared object that should have been built during installation. It would be nice to see the output of that install. You could try [submitting an issue on the github project page](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/issues) as this doesn't really sound like a general R problem.